# I'm not able to click save button for posting a news / publication

Tags: php, mysql, apache, codeigniter, cpanel

I'm experiencing an issue after my hosting provider update their cPanel Server to the new Server.

The old one has a specification like below:

```
Apache Version  2.2.29
PHP Version 5.5.21
MySQL Version   5.5.47-cll
```

The new Server has a new specification:

```
Apache Version  2.4.23
PHP Version 5.6.29
MySQL Version   10.0.29-MariaDB
```

I'm unable to add and post any news to my website. It didn't respond anything when I click the Save button.

[image]

But the weird thing is when I tried on my local using XAMMP with the same specification of the new server which are 
:

```
Apache Version  2.4.23
PHP Version 5.6.29
MySQL Version   10.0.29-MariaDB
```

I'm able to create and post news to my website.

My question is would it be the security for the files or do you have any clue?

Comment: Apache version or php version doesn't have to do anything with html requests, if you are submitting your request through ajax try clearing your browsers cache

Comment: Hi Divyank, I have tried access using other browser and I'm also try accessing using different computer. It still the same I can't click the save button. Do you have any clue for this?